# I'm confused by the notation in this question

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics

The context of this question is about the gradient descent algorithm and the question is, consider the function f : R^2 → R given by

```
f <- function(x) (x[1]-1)ˆ2 + 100*(x[1]ˆ2-x[2])ˆ2
```

Give a short mathematical proof that f has a unique minimum.

I'm unsure what the x[1] and x[2] represent here.

Comment: x is a vector with two components and x[1] and x[2] are those two components.

Comment: That's not really *notation*, it's just R code.

Answer (score 1):

As others commented this is just expressing a function from using mathematical notation in R code. The function in question is $f(x) = (x_1-1)^2 + 100*(x_1^2-x_2)^2$ and as it suggests it take a vector from $\mathbb{R}^2$ and maps it to $\mathbb{R}$. Some computer languages (e.g. C or Python) start indexing the components of a vector from `0` and some from `1`, as in the latter category. As such `x[1]` refers to the first component of vector `x` and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, this makes sense now. So to find the global minimum, would I show that the second derivative is >0? I'm getting a little confused on how to differentiate this function.

Comment: Yes, if $\frac{df}{dx}(x_a) = 0$ and $\frac{d^2 f}{d x^2}(x_a)> 0$, then $f(x_a)$ is a *local* minimum. Whether or not is global it will depend on $f$ being *strictly* convex function, $f$ being twice continuously differentiable implies that it is [*strongly* convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions).